# libGDX Java (Desktop): SelectBox throwing exception

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have an issue creating a select box for my application. I couldn't find a solution anywhere else.
My code:

```
public class OptionsMenu implements Screen{
    private Stage stage = new Stage();

    private Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("jsonurlhere"), new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("atlasurlhere")));

    private String[] viewmodes = new String[] {"Fullscreen", "Windowed"};
    private SelectBox<String> viewmode;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        viewmode = new SelectBox<String>(skin);        
        viewmode.setItems(viewmodes);
        viewmode.setSelected("Fullscreen");

        stage.addActor(viewmode);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(100, 100, 100, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is not the complete code, just the relevant parts to the selectbox.

My error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.layout(SelectBox.java:193)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Widget.validate(Widget.java:88)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.getPrefWidth(SelectBox.java:290)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.<init>(SelectBox.java:80)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.<init>(SelectBox.java:71)
    at com.lockedprogramming.pacificblitz.screens.OptionsMenu.show(OptionsMenu.java:49)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.lockedprogramming.pacificblitz.PacificBlitz.create(PacificBlitz.java:18)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Eclipse shows no errors before runtime, and if I comment out the following lines the program throws no exception:

```
//viewmode = new SelectBox<String>(skin);
//viewmode.setItems(viewmodes);
//viewmode.setSelected("Fullscreen");
//stage.addActor(viewmode);
```

EDIT: My .json code:

```
{
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
        default: {
            font: menufontblack, background: menubuttondefault,
            listStyle: { font: menufontblack, selection: menubuttonhover },
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: please,  show also your skin's json file. Something seems to be wrong with SelectBox style.

Comment: Just added it @donfuxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no ScrollStyle defined** in your SelectBoxStyle definition of the skin json file. I am pretty sure that is the problem in your case. I could reproduce the problem in one of my libgdx projects by removing the ScrollStyle declaration.

Try the following and just set the default ScrollStyle for your SelectBox:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        font: menufontblack, background: menubuttondefault,
        scrollStyle: default,
        listStyle: { font: menufontblack, selection: menubuttonhover },
    },
}
```

You can also see the example uiskin json file here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json

**Update:** you'll also need to define a scrollstyle in the json then. something like:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: { vScroll: default-scroll, hScrollKnob: default-round-large, background: default-rect, hScroll: default-scroll, vScrollKnob: default-round-large }
},
```

The best is you check the uiskin example at github to see how those textures look like https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin#overview

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me `No com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle registered with name: default`
Do I need to create a ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle section and what assets would that require (textures etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Exception message seem to point that the creation of the SelectBox item fail at line 193 of the class SelectBox; it cant set the layout so it return null and its not accepted ie the way you instantiate SelectBox/Skin is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I go about fixing it? Would you need the code from other sections or the .json file?

Comment: Post the contents of SelectBox.java

Comment: Thats the original libGDX class, you can find it online, and that probably wont help anyway